# Alfresco: Combine multiple Files to one PDF

Tags: alfresco

i try to merge multiple Files (PDF and TIF) to one PDF Bundle. I want to print all Documents from one Workspace. Any Suggestions how to do it with alfresco?

Thx
Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PDF merging out of the box in Alfresco. You should have a look at [Jared Ottley's PDF Toolkit](http://jared.ottleys.net/uncategorized/alfresco-pdf-toolkit). It implements Alfresco actions to work with PDF documents, merging PDFs being one of them. Personally I have not used it and it looks a bit dated but it should get you started.